# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp64\www\Proiect\aplicatie\user_check.php on line 18

Tags: php, users, errors

```
//register users

$username= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
$password1= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password1']);
$password2= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password2']);

//form validation

if(empty($username)){array_push($errors, "Username is required")};
if(empty($email)) {array_push($errors, "Email is required")};
if(empty($password)) {array_push($errors, "Password is required")};
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of context with your code?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a WP question, you should ask general PHP questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

The semi-colons need to go inside the curly braces, to mark the ends of the array_push() statements:

```
if(empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
if(empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
if(empty($password)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
```

You don't need semi-colons after the close braces.